# Exception thrown: write access violation

Tags: c++, list, exception, data-structures, runtime-error

I am trying to implement a list structure, but when I wrote the insert() function which inserts an element in a specific position in the list, I get an error **Exception thrown: write access violation.
pl was 0x34812B3A.**
I tried alot to fix it but I really can't. I used try..throw..catch and still didn't get it, so what should I do.
This is my code:

List.h

```
#pragma once
#define MAXLIST 100

typedef struct List {
    int size;
    int entry[MAXLIST];
    
}list;

void createl(list*); 
int ListEmpty(list*); 
int ListFull(list*);
int sizel(list*);
void destroyl(list*); 
void insert(int, int, list*);
void deletei(int* , int, list*); 
void traversel(list*, void (*)(int));
void retrieve(int*, int, list*);
void replace(int, int, list*);
//int access(int , list*);
```

and this is the implementation (List.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

void createl(list* pl) {
    pl->size = 0;
}

int isEmpty(list* pl) {
    return !(pl->size);
}

int isFull(list* pl) {
    return (pl->size == MAXLIST);
}

int sizel(list* pl) {
    return pl->size;
}

void destroyl(list* pl) {
    pl->size = 0;
}

void insert(int e, int p, list* pl) {   //insert element e in the postion p in the list
    for (int i = pl->size -1; i >= p; i--) {
        pl->entry[i+1] = pl->entry[i];
    }
    pl->entry[p] = e;
    pl->size++;
}

void deletei(int* pe, int p, list* pl) {
    *pe = pl->entry[p];
    for (int i = p + 1; i < pl->size; ++i) {
        pl->entry[i-1] = pl->entry[i];
    }
    pl->size--;
}

void traversel(list* pl, void (*pf)(int e)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pl->size; ++i) {
        (*pf)(pl->entry[i]);
    }
}

void retrieve(int* pe, int p, list* pl) {
    *pe = pl->entry[p];
}


void replace(int e, int p, list* pl) {
    pl->entry[p] = e;
}

/*int access(int p, list* pl) {
    return pl->entry[p];
}*/
```

I get the error here in function insert()

```
pl->entry[p] = e;
```

and this is a program to just check if my code works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

void display(int e) {
    cout << e << "\n";
}

int main() {
    list l;
    list* ptl = &l;
    int t;
    cout << "Put 5 elements:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cin >> t;
        insert(t, sizel(ptl), ptl);
    }
    cout << "The list looks like a stack\n\n";
    traversel(ptl, display);
    cout << "The size of the list is: " << sizel(ptl) << endl;
    insert(9, 2, ptl);
    cout << "The size of the list is: " << sizel(ptl) << endl;
    int temp;
    deletei(&temp, 2, ptl);
    cout << temp <<endl ;
    traversel(ptl, display);
    cout << "The size of the list is: " << sizel(&l) << endl;
    int t2;
    retrieve(&t2, 2, ptl);
    cout << t2 << endl;
    replace(4, 1, ptl);
    traversel(ptl, display);
    destroyl(ptl);
    cout << "The size of the list is: " << sizel(ptl) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time and helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You used `ptl`, which points at `l`, without initializing `l`.

Add initialization like this:

```
int main() {
    list l;
    list* ptl = &l;
    int t;
    createl(ptl); // add initialization
    cout << "Put 5 elements:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cin >> t;
        insert(t, sizel(ptl), ptl);
    }
```

Comment: I also used &l without intializing ptl and have the same problem, I created (stack and queue with array implementation) and didn't get this problem, So can you sujest a solution for me.